# How to use multiple filters + map in the same stream?

Tags: java, filter, java-stream

How do I merge this to a single stream?  The goal is to get all the row numbers in a single list.

```java
List<Integer> Type1ErrorRows = errors.stream()
        .filter(c -> (c.getClass() == Type1Error.class))
        .map(c -> ((Type1Error) c).getRowNumber())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Integer> Type2ErrorRows = errors.stream()
        .filter(c -> (c.getClass() == Type2Error.class))
        .map(c -> ((Type2Error) c).getRowNumber())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Integer> rowNumbers =
        Stream.concat(Type1ErrorRows.stream(), Type2ErrorRows.stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: You don't. There's no "splitting" streams in two, at least not in the standard library. But you can do it with a single loop, which isn't just easier to write but also easier to read and maintain.

Comment: @krenks Why don't you just call addAll on the first list passing the second one as argument. Otherwise, if you wanna have another one list, regardless those ones, you could create another one list and then call addAll() for each of the two lists.

Comment: Where does `getRowNumber()` come from? If it's from common superclass/interface you  can group by the class and collect to map.

Comment: After the question update, just make an interface with `getRowNumber` and have both types implement it. No splitting or `instanceof` needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume that a common interface exists, otherwise all the required casting will make it too cumbersome for streams.

```
public interface ErrorInterface {

  int getRowNumber();
}
```

Filter that object's class is allowed, cast, invoke method to get row number.

```
Set<Class<?>> allowedClasses = Set.of(Type1Error.class, Type2Error.class);
List<Integer> rowNumbers = errors.stream()
        .filter(err -> allowedClasses.contains(err.getClass()))
        .map(err -> (ErrorInterface) err)
        .map(ErrorInterface::getRowNumber)
        .toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Streams are not the right tool for this job. Just use a loop:

```
List<Integer> type1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> type2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (Error error : errors) {
  if (error instanceof Type1Error e1) {
    type1.add(e1.getRowNumber());
  }
  else if (error instanceof Type2Error e2) {
    type2.add(e2.getRowNumber());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using the [`Stream.mapMulti`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer)) method added in Java 16:

```java
List<Integer> rowNumbers = errors.stream().<Integer>mapMulti((c, consumer) -> {
    if (c.getClass() == Type1Error.class) {
        consumer.accept(((Type1Error) c).getRowNumber());
    } else if (c.getClass() == Type2Error.class) {
        consumer.accept(((Type2Error) c).getRowNumber());
    }
}).toList();
```

This keeps and uses the row number of any value with class exactly equal to `Type1Error` or `Type2Error`, and discards the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using [`Stream.flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)):

```java
List<Integer> rowNumbers = errors.stream().flatMap(c -> {
    if (c.getClass() == Type1Error.class) {
        return Stream.of(((Type1Error) c).getRowNumber());
    } else if (c.getClass() == Type2Error.class) {
        return Stream.of(((Type2Error) c).getRowNumber());
    } else {
        return Stream.empty();
    }
}).toList();
```

This maps each value whose class is exactly equal to `Type1Error` or `Type2Error` to a single-element stream containing the row number, and maps all other values to the empty map.

If you're OK matching using `instanceof` rather than the more specific `getClass() == clazz`, the following is an analogous solution using the [Pattern Matching for switch Expressions and Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/language/pattern-matching-switch-expressions-and-statements.html#GUID-E69EEA63-E204-41B4-AA7F-D58B26A3B232) feature introduced in Java 21:

```java
List<Integer> rowNumbers = errors.stream().flatMap(c -> switch (c) {
    case Type1Error e -> Stream.of(e.getRowNumber());
    case Type2Error e -> Stream.of(e.getRowNumber());
    default -> Stream.empty();
}).toList();
```